# How to add a custom directive div after nth ng-repeat item

Tags: html, angularjs

In my code i have a bunch of items rendered by ng-repeat. 
These items use the bootstrap class *col-md-3*
and i'd like to add a feature which allows the user to see a large detail panel by clicking on one of these items.

However i'd like to accomplish it by having only one detail panel in my DOM and moving it around.

The html is like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="thing in thingsCtrl.things">
  <thing-widget class="col-md-3"></thing-widget>
</div>

<thing-detail ng-show="thingsCtrl.showDetail" class="col-md-12"> </thing-detail>
```

any chance to accomplish?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try moving the thing-detail inside the ng-repeat and use $index to add it or not.

```
<div ng-repeat="thing in thingsCtrl.things">
  <thing-widget class="col-md-3"></thing-widget>
  <thing-detail ng-if="$index === nth" ng-show="thingsCtrl.showDetail" class="col-md-12"> </thing-detail> 
</div>
```

Comment: i tried this solution, but i want only one detail-panel in my DOM.

Comment: There's only one $index that will match the ngIf, so you will have only one detail-panel inside your DOM.

Comment: would i be able to move the panel depending on the item clicked by the user?

Comment: If you add another value to control the visibility onClick, yes. Istead of using the $index you could evaluate any other value.